# My .batch code is not working, can't find why

Tags: batch-file

I've created a .bat to help my classmates to compile and run our java homework, but ins't working. 
Before it was two .bat files and it worked all fine, but since I've tried to make just one, it ceased working.

```
   @echo off

   setlocal EnableExtensions

   title Algoritmos 1 - SUPER TOOL!

   color a

   :Menu

   <menu with option C and J>

   set /p mode=
   if %mode%==C (
    goto MenuC 
   ) else if %menu%==J (
    goto MenuJ
   ) else if NOT %whatapp%==e (
    echo Menu inválido!
    pause
   )

   :MenuC

   <code that works>

   goto MenuC

   :MenuJ

   <code that works>

   pause
   goto MenuJ
```

Comment: In what was has it ceased working?

Comment: When I open it and type C or J (or anything) it just closes, not even a error  appears in the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Please don't just link to your code--add it directly to your question. If possible, create an [mcve]. This makes it a lot easier for other users to help you. May you live long and gather many upvotes :)

Comment: lines 17 - 22: check your variable names. You might be also interested in using `if` with the `/i` switch.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, and thanks Stephan, the /i turned to be very usefull :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch does not support `if else` constructions but only `if .. (..) else (..)`
When you are using if with still not defined variables you might need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) .Check if this works:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion

title Algoritmos 1 - SUPER TOOL!

color a

:Menu
cls
echo.
echo ===========================================================
echo //       Gostaria de compilar (C) ou Executar (J)?       //
echo ===========================================================
echo.

set /p mode=
if !mode!==C (
    goto MenuC 
) 
 if !menu!==J (
    goto MenuJ
) 
 if NOT !whatapp!==e (
    echo Menu inválido!
    pause
)

:MenuC
cls
echo.
echo ===========================================================
echo //  ESTE BAT FUNCIONA APENAS COM OS NOMES JA EXISTENTES! //
echo ===========================================================
echo //  Que exercicio você gostaria de compilar?             //
echo //  (Digite como está no lado esquerdo da lista)         //
echo ===========================================================
echo //   1 - Exercicio 1                                     //
echo //   2 - Exercicio 2                                     //
echo //   3 - Exercicio 3                                     //
echo //   4 - Exercicio 4                                     //
echo //   5 - Exercicio 5                                     //
echo //   6 - Exercicio 6                                     //
echo //   7 - Exercicio 7                                     //
echo //   8 - Exercicio 8                                     //
echo //   9 - Exercicio 9                                     //
echo //   9+ - Exercicio 9 Extra                              //
echo //   10 - Exercicio 10                                   //
echo //   11 - Exercicio 11                                   //
echo //   12 - Exercicio 12                                   //
echo //   13 - Exercicio 13                                   //
echo //   14 - Exercicio 14                                   //
echo //   15 - Exercicio 15                                   //
echo //   16 - Exercicio 16                                   //
echo //   17 - Exercicio 17                                   //
echo //   18 - Exercicio 18                                   //
echo //   19 - Exercicio 19                                   //
echo //   20 - Exercicio 20                                   //
echo //   21 - Exercicio 21                                   //
echo //   22 - Exercicio 22                                   //
echo //   22B - Exercicio 22B                                 //
echo ===========================================================
echo //  a - Todos              //  e - Fecha este programa   //
echo ===========================================================
echo.

set /p Co=
if !Co!==a (
    javac Exercicio1.java
    echo 1/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio2.java
    echo 2/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio3.java
    echo 3/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio4.java
    echo 4/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio5.java
    echo 5/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio6.java
    echo 6/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio7.java
    echo 7/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio8.java
    echo 8/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio9.java
    echo 9/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio9Extra.java
    echo 9 Extra/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio10.java
    echo 10/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio11.java
    echo 11/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio12.java
    echo 12/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio13.java
    echo 13/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio14.java
    echo 14/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio15.java
    echo 15/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio16.java
    echo 16/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio17.java
    echo 17/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio18.java
    echo 18/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio19.java
    echo 19/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio20.java
    echo 20/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio21.java
    echo 21/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio22.java
    echo 22/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio22B.java
    echo 22B/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio22B.java
    echo 23/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio22B.java
    echo 24/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio22B.java
    echo 25/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio22B.java
    echo 26/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio22B.java
    echo 27/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio22B.java
    echo 28/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio22B.java
    echo 29/30
    pause
    javac Exercicio22B.java
    echo 30/30
    pause
    echo Concluido
) 
if !Co!==e (
    echo ERRO
) 
if NOT !Co!==e (
    javac Exercicio%Co%.java
    pause 
)
goto MenuC

:MenuJ
cls
echo ===========================================================
echo //  Que exercicio você gostaria de abrir?                //
echo ===========================================================
echo //   1 - Exercicio 1                                     //
echo //   2 - Exercicio 2                                     //
echo //   3 - Exercicio 3                                     //
echo //   4 - Exercicio 4                                     //
echo //   5 - Exercicio 5                                     //
echo //   6 - Exercicio 6                                     //
echo //   7 - Exercicio 7                                     //
echo //   8 - Exercicio 8                                     //
echo //   9 - Exercicio 9                                     //
echo //   9+ - Exercicio 9 Extra                              //
echo //   10 - Exercicio 10                                   //
echo //   11 - Exercicio 11                                   //
echo //   12 - Exercicio 12                                   //
echo //   13 - Exercicio 13                                   //
echo //   14 - Exercicio 14                                   //
echo //   15 - Exercicio 15                                   //
echo //   16 - Exercicio 16                                   //
echo //   17 - Exercicio 17                                   //
echo //   18 - Exercicio 18                                   //
echo //   19 - Exercicio 19                                   //
echo //   20 - Exercicio 20                                   //
echo //   21 - Exercicio 21                                   //
echo //   22 - Exercicio 22                                   //
echo //   22B - Exercicio 22B                                 //
echo ===========================================================
echo.

set /p whatapp=

java Exercicio%whatapp%

pause
goto MenuJ
```